# iOS 7 XCode 5 Storyboard Layout Example

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, uistoryboard

I'm trying to create a dead simple storyboard app with a layout similar to the following. I've got the list/detail view setup but I can't figure out how to link additional pages. I want the "go" page to be my start page and drive off that.

Can someone help me with a dead simple example solution on how you would set this up? I'm trying to use "push" segues.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are different ways to create a segues:

**1 - From Control To Controller:**

[image: From Cell To detail Controller]

---

**2 - Using Connection Inspector**

[image: Using Connection Inspector]

---

**3 - From View Controller to View Controller**

[image: From View Controller to View Controlle!]

---

- **#1** and **#3** you will need to hold <kbd>control</kbd> before
  dragging.
- **#2** & **#3** :
  You will need to give an identifier to your segue, unlike **#1** You have to performe the segue using code:

add identifier:

[image]

Perform the segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:sender];
```

Now here is the thing, this will just perform the segue, if you ever needed to pass some data to that view controller. Then you have to implement the following segue deleguate:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"])
    {
        //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Push segues will not work until you embed your view controller hierarchy in a UINavigationController. You can place one as root view controller for your GO view controller and then it should work

Comment: it seems as though you are using modals everywhere which isn't the route i want to go, thanks though

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting your answer... If you want to use a PUSH segue you NEED a UINavigation controller. Push segues won't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for example by ctrl click on a button and then move the mouse to your target view controller and release.

I've created a very simple example in my blog:

http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.de/2014/02/howto-add-view-controllers-to.html