# Navigation controller sometimes pushes to black screen using storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5, xcode-storyboard

I'm using storyboard in Xcode 5 and I'm trying to push to a UIViewController from a UITableViewController that's housed in a UINavigationController, but I sometimes get a black screen (probably 75% of the time).  From reading other posts, I've learned to use the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method to instantiate the view controller I'm pushing to prior to pushing, so my code looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.row < self.objects.count) {
        PFObject *retrievedProduct = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Product *product = [[Product alloc] init];

        // set properties for retrieved product 
        // (code omitted)

        //load product detail page
        self.detailPage = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MPDetailPageViewController"];
        self.detailPage.product = product;

        //Bring to detail page
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailPage animated:YES];

    } else if (self.paginationEnabled) {
        // load more
        [self loadNextPage];
    }
}
```

And in MPDetailPageViewController I do an NSLog in viewDidAppear and even when the screen is black, it is still printing.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Did you add a storyBoardId Identifier on the storyboard

Comment: Yes, the ViewController I'm pushing to has the Storyboard ID "MPDetailPageViewController"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if this works for you:

first make sure the header file is imported:

```
#import "MPDetailPageViewController.h"
```

then do this:

```
//the storyboard
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.navigationController.storyboard;

//the detail controller
MPDetailPageViewController *detailPage = [storyboard 
           instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MPDetailPageViewController"];
//set the product
detailPage.product = product;
//Push to detail View
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailPage animated:YES];
```

<kbd>[PROJECT NO SEGUE](https://mega.co.nz/#!rdoEUZRL!YarFlDosLHBh0gSkJq99lbxcqbQewYr3CA5yJCbEiWA)</kbd>

---

Unless you really have to, it is more difficult (more code) to push views programmatically.

Just create a segue in storyboard please refer to [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476998/ios-7-xcode-5-storyboard-layout-example/22519153#22519153) if your not sure.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.row < self.objects.count) {
        //perform the segue
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:sender];
    } else if (self.paginationEnabled) {
        // load more
        [self loadNextPage];
    }
}
```

Now you can move all that other code to the following segue deleguate:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    PFObject *retrievedProduct = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Product *product = [[Product alloc] init];

    MPDetailPageViewController *detailVC = (MPDetailPageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    detailVC.product = product;
 }
}
```

<kbd>[PROJECT USING SEGUE](https://mega.co.nz/#!ncIDTBiQ!kc3tsWfdpAjVxD-TnSSPvJaTaQ1ExfoWK7-av_HPFwA)</kbd>

Comment: @user3217366 have you considered a `push segue` it will be easier

Comment: is there an example you could point me to?  Should this be done programmatically or via Storyboard?

Comment: @user3217366 using storyboard, sure matter of facts I wrote an answer like that, [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22519153/1880431)

Comment: in that example do all 3 methods accomplish the exact same thing? Since I need to pass that "product" object, should I use method 2 or 3 (and not 1)?

Comment: Yes they are the same use whichever you prefer, you will need to use the deleguate to pass the product, I edited my post so you see how this should be done

Comment: Still showing a black screen unfortunately. Maybe it has something to do with the MPDetailPageViewController class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50166/discussion-between-meda-and-user3217366)